# How to specify the cuda version in sagemaker training instance

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently using tensorflow 2.3 to train a CNN model on AWS sagemaker. I want to run the training on an GPU instance but it seem that the default cuda version is cuda 10.0 but what I need is cuda 10.1. I need a way to specify the cuda version in the training instance. I use estimator.Tensorflow which consumes a script file, not a docker image.

Comment: The [Deep Learning container for TensorFlow `2.3.0` offers support for CUDA `10.2`](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/aws-deep-learning-containers-with-tensorflow-2-3-0/), and the [container for TensorFlow `2.3.1` offers support for CUDA `11.0`](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/aws-deep-learning-containers-for-tensorflow-2-3-1-with-cuda-11-0/)